# Passing data to other layers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

select_col = 'My_Col'

ggplot(dat %>% rename(My_Col = x), aes(x = .data[[select_col]])) +
  geom_histogram(stat = 'density', fill = 'red', colour = 'red')
```

Now I want to add another layer with normal plot. I tried this

```
stat_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, sd = sd(dat[[select_col]])), linewidth = 1.5)
```

However I wonder if I could do something like `.data[[select_col]]`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing because for some reason you are trying to dynamically rename a column in your data frame as well as draw the desired plot. If it were not for this complication, the answer would be very straightforward:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(dat, aes(x)) + 
  geom_density(fill = 'red', color = 'red') +
  geom_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, mean(dat$x), sd(dat$x)))
```

[image]

Note that we can just use `geom_density` instead of `geom_histogram` with `stat_density`.

If for some reason you *have* to do the dynamic renaming using `select_col`, then you can do something like:

```r
library(dplyr)

select_col <- 'My_Col'

ggplot(rename(dat, !!enquo(select_col) := x), 
       aes(x = .data[[select_col]])) +
  geom_density(fill = 'red', colour = 'red') +
  geom_function(fun = \(x) {
    dnorm(x, mean = mean(rename(dat, !!enquo(select_col) := x)[[select_col]]),
          sd = sd(rename(dat, !!enquo(select_col) := x)[[select_col]]))
    })
```

[image]

I have a hunch that you may be trying to do this to create a function which takes arbitrary data and plots the density and normal distribution. If so, you could just do:

```r
density_with_normal <- function(data, column, new_name) {
  
  vals <- data[[deparse(substitute(column))]]
  
  ggplot(data, aes({{column}})) +
    geom_density(fill = 'red', colour = 'red') +
    geom_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, mean(vals), sd(vals))) +
    xlab(deparse(substitute(new_name)))
}
```

Which allows, for example

```r
density_with_normal(mtcars, hp, Horsepower)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In your second example you use `rename` twice. First one to pass data to `ggplot` and second one in `dnorm` function. I want to avoid that! I believe, there should be some way to use data as defined against data argument of `ggplot` function, and then flow that information in subsequent layer, something like using generic `.data[[]]`